# Select random string from array unless it equals something

Tags: php, arrays, random

I pick a random color in a foreach loop, how do i make sure that the chosen color isnt the last color that was chosen?

This is an example of my current code:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$colors = array('#61AE24', '#EAE672', '#00A1CB', '#E54028', '#E59B28', '#28E4E5', '#DB28E5');
foreach($array as $val) {
    $color = $colors[array_rand($colors)];
    echo '<div style="color: '.$color.';">'.$val.'</div>';
}
```

I need to make sure that the same color isnt used next to eachother.

Thanks

Comment: So you just want that you can't pick a value twice in a row?

Comment: yes, well explained!

Comment: Then you probably want to use the `$_SESSION` array if you want to do this over multiple requests.

Comment: was hoping for a solution without using sessions. plus once i have the 'last chosen value' how could i specifically disallow that value from being chosen?

Comment: ok, can you show the expected output color sequence? Show how such sequence should be rendered ideally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not picking a random colour in each iteration, you've actually picked it outside of the loop. I've moved it into the loop for you.

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$colors = array('#61AE24', '#EAE672', '#00A1CB', '#E54028', '#E59B28', '#28E4E5', '#DB28E5');
$lastcolor = NULL;
foreach($array as $val) {
    while (empty($color) || $color == $lastcolor) {
        $color = $colors[array_rand($colors)];
    }
    $lastcolor = $color;
    echo '<div style="color: '.$color.';">'.$val.'</div>';
}
```

A few things to note:

- `$lastcolor` is defined outside of the loop so it persists between iterations
- We set the `$color`, then the `$color` is checked against `$lastcolor`, assigning a new random color until they don't match
- Finally, `$lastcolor` is set to your new color for the next iteration check

The other alternative solution is to remove the last colour from `$colors` in a temporary array:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$colors = array('#61AE24', '#EAE672', '#00A1CB', '#E54028', '#E59B28', '#28E4E5', '#DB28E5');
$lastcolor = NULL;
foreach($array as $val) {
    $temp_colors = $colors;
    if (($key = array_search($lastcolor, $temp_colors)) !== false) {
        unset($temp_colors[$key]);
    }
    $color = $temp_colors[array_rand($temp_colors)];
    $lastcolor = $color;
    echo '<div style="color: '.$color.';">'.$val.'</div>';
}
```

The first solution is more likely to have better performance, assuming the number of iterations in the `while` loop doesn't exceed the number of elements in `$colors`.

Comment: I like your first solution, it works great, simple and effective!

Comment: Surely you could just do `foreach ($array as $val) { shuffle($colors); $color = array_shift($colors); }`? Assuming you don't need to reuse `$colors` elsewhere in the script

Comment: @BenSwinburne I assumed that `$array` could have more elements than `$colors`, otherwise sure

Comment: But if that was the case the iterations of array > the size of colours wouldn't have a colour assigned at all.

Comment: @BenSwinburne I don't understand what you mean. In my answer, the colours could be reused infinitely. OP just doesn't want adjacent colours.

Comment: I like your first solution, although you could omit the first `$color = $colors[array_rand($colors)];` line in the foreach loop to keep things a little simpler

Comment: @JonStory `$color` would be undefined if I skipped that. I could try and combine the undefined condition in the while loop, though.

Comment: @JonStory Just edited. It was my initial approach but I was keeping my workflow simpler until I had time to check the logic.

Comment: @sjagr indeed, and doesn't PHP evaulate that as null? (I could be wrong, I don't work in PHP much now) So it would just enter the while loop. Unless $color is discarded at the end of the foreach, in which case just define `$color = null;` alongside `$lastcolor` :)

Comment: @JonStory Sure, it would evaluate it as `NULL` with a notice, and the conditional would try and compare `NULL` equality to a previously defined colour value such as `#61AE24`, which would be false. Thus, the `while` loop would never execute without that `empty` check I just added. The only exception is the very first iteration of the `foreach` in which `$lastcolor` is indeed `NULL`.

Comment: @sjagr then the simpler solution is just to define `$color = null;` before the foreach, which will retain both values from the assignment `$lastcolor = $color`, and therefore enter the while loop at the start of each iteration of the foreach. The `empty()` call works too, though, so this is really just debating detail now :p

Comment: @JonStory No, that wouldn't work. You'd only get colours half the time. Please work through the iterations, comparing what the values of `$lastcolor` and `$color` would be, even if I did previously set `$color` to `NULL` before the `while` loop. For example, you would have #1: `NULL == NULL` (true), #2: `NULL == '#61AE24` (false), and `$lastcolor = NULL;` as a result, then #3: `NULL == NULL` (true), and the pattern repeats itself. The `empty` call handles this better without the hit/miss issue.

Comment: @JonStory I see now, I didn't notice your mention of it being declared before the `foreach` in your comments, and thought you were saying to declare it before the `while`. I agree then it's just semantics. I only have a preference to mine because it's a little more self-explanatory on what's going on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` to filter the colors out:

```
<?php
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$colors = array('#61AE24', '#EAE672', '#00A1CB', '#E54028', '#E59B28', '#28E4E5', '#DB28E5');
$color = "";
foreach($array as $val)
{
    $filteredColors = array_filter($colors, function($v) { global $color; return $v != $color; });
    $color = $filteredColors[array_rand($filteredColors)];
    echo '<div style="color: '.$color.';">'.$val.'</div>';
}
```